# RowBackground and AlternatingRowBackground properties doesnt work inside Style tag

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

When I try to display alternate colors in my datagrid rows, 
both RowBackground and AlternatingRowBackground works when used inside Datagrid tag like this :

```
<DataGrid Name="datagrid"
     RowBackground="CadetBlue"
     AlternatingRowBackground="LightBlue">
```

But when i used this properties inside Style tag like this ,

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
        <Setter Property="RowBackground" Value="CadetBlue" />
        <Setter Property="AlternatingRowBackground" Value="LightBlue" />
</Style>
```

It doesnt work. 
Can someone tell me the reason behind this. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is working fine here.have u written style in resource ??

Comment: Thank you . . I forgot to add Style in Resource. I got the solution now.